# Fast cross product of each column of matrix

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I wish to evaluate:

[image: $$ X = \frac{\sum^I_{i=1} (v - v_i)(v - v_i)'}{dd'} $$]

v_i is the distinct elements of a cross product b_i b_i'.

I think that the code below should work (disregarding the division), but its too slow to even test. What is the fastest way to perform the above in R? Is EigenCpp the way to go?

```
   library(Matrix)
   library(pracma)
   columncrossprod <- function(x){
     x_s <- Matrix(x, sparse = TRUE) 
     tt <- x_s %*% t(x_s)
     tt <- as.matrix(tt)
     tt <- tt[row(tt) <= col(tt)]
     return(tt)
   }
   v_i = apply(b,2,columncrossprod)

   # repeat the matrix m across the space of y_i
   Mr<-repmat(M,ncol(y_i),1)
   Mr <- t(Mr)
   # perform the inner subtraction
   nom <- Mr - y_i
   # cross product
   nom2 <- nom %*% nom
```

For reference, the matrix b is 63 x 8638, v is a 2016x1, v_i and therefore nom becomes 2016 x 8638.

Comment: `Matrix` is not base R right? Please include any packages you use

Comment: Apologies - I'm using Matrix for the sparse matrices, and pracma for repmat functionality